# When I am iterating through each element in a list, I am getting a list with 'nan' elements, why?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to multiply each element in a list by using a for loop to iterate through each element in the list. Here's my code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('spec.txt') #Reading in the text file
frequency_data = data[:,0] 

h = 6.626e-27 #Planck constant in erg s
c = 2.998e10 #speed of light (in vacuum) in cm/s
k = 1.381e-16 



def Bv(v,T):                
    k1 = (2.0*h)/(c**2)
    x2 = (h*v)/(k*T)
    return k1*((v**3)/(np.exp(x2) -1))
```

I tried to iterate through each element in the list
**Bv(frequency_data, 2.275)**.

```
BB_v = []

for k in range(len(frequency_data)):
    c = Bv(frequency_data, 2.275)[k]*10**17
    BB_v.append(c)

print(BB_v)
```

Ouput:

```
[0.0, inf, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
 nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
 nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:7: RuntimeWarning: divide 
by zero encountered in true_divide
import sys/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:6:RuntimeWarning: 
divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
```

But I am getting a list with 'nan' elements. Why am I getting a list with 'nan' elements?

[Link to the data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iNfY6xPGsFGz-xpPqXPLbXjC8YJTFhne)

Comment: Looks for me as if you wanted to do  `for k in Bv(frequency_data, 2.275): BB_v.append(k*10**17)` ?

Comment: We do not have your input data, please provide  a  [mre] with some hardcoded data to replicate your error and advise on how to fix it.

Comment: Hi, I have reduced my code and provided the input data. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

This not related to iteration since we can reproduce the problem with only one single value.

The value of x2 is very close to zero causing the denominator np.exp(x2)-1 to be numericaly equivalent to zero due to machine precision :

```
def Bv(v,T):                
    k1 = (2.0*h)/(c**2)
    x2 = (h*v)/(k*T)
    print("x2={}".format(x2))
    return k1*((v**3)/(np.exp(x2) -1)) 


print(Bv(1., 2.275))
```

Give the result :

```
x2=4.160753532182104e-28
nan

/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
```

To avoid this you should rewrite the formulation of the fraction inside Bv so that it is numericaly compatible with small values of x2. For example, you could do a Taylor expansion around zero :

np.exp(x) tend to 1+x when x tend to zero

so np.exp(x)-1 should tend to x

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your two big problems are:

```
   c = Bv(...) # <-- you are overwriting the constant c here
```

and

```
    x2 = (...*...)/(k*...) # <-- you use k here instead of perhaps k1?
```

If you are running this all in the same module, then `k` will be a global defined in your for loop as `0`. So on the first iteration `x2` will evaluate to an array of zeroes. This means the return value will be an array of infinities (`<float> / 0`). Meaning at the end of the `c == np.array([inf, ...])`. Finally, this means on the second iteration, `k1` evaluates to `0` (`<float> / c**2`, where `c=inf`). This means your return statement evaluates to `inf / 0` which produces your "not a number" result.

To fix, you need to do at least one of:

- Use `ALL_CAPS` for constant names -- making it harder to accidentally overwrite them
- Choose more verbose variable names so you are less likely to get name clashes (per the constant `c` (speed of light) and your temporary variable `c` (used to store the result of `Bv(...)`).
- write all logic in functions and not at the global/module scope. This will help avoid functions picking up non-constant variables defined at the global/module scope (eg. `k` from your for loop).

Secondly, you then need to evaluate whether you want `k1` or `k` in this statement `x2 = (h*v)/(k*T)` (see the second point about choosing more verbose variable names to avoid name clashes).